# Correct solution to these ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have three linear ODEs that I would like to solve:

$$
-\frac{\mathrm{d}y_1}{\mathrm{d}x} = \delta(x-a) \text{ with } y_1(x_{max})=0 \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y_2}{\mathrm{d}x^2} = \delta(x-a) \text{ with } y_2(x_{max})=0, \frac{\mathrm{d}y_2}{\mathrm{d}x}(x_{max}) = 0 \\
-\frac{\mathrm{d}^3y_3}{\mathrm{d}x^3} = \delta(x-a) \text{ with } y_3(x_{max})=0, \frac{\mathrm{d}y_3}{\mathrm{d}x}(x_{max}) = 0, \frac{\mathrm{d}^2y_3}{\mathrm{d}x^2}(x_{max}) = 0
$$
where $ x \in D = [0, x_{max}], a\in D$ and $\delta$ is the Dirac-delta function.

I tried applying Laplace transforms however they require knowledge of the $y_i$ functions at the point $0$ which I do not have. So, I've solved the first equation in the following way
$$
-\int\limits_{x}^{x_{max}} \frac{\mathrm{d}y_1}{\mathrm{d}x'} \mathrm{d}x' = \int\limits_{x}^{x_{max}} \delta(x'-a) \mathrm{d}x' = 
\begin{cases}
1 \text{ when } 0 \leq x<a,\\
0 \text{ when } a<x \leq x_{max}.
\end{cases} \iff \\
y_1(x) = \begin{cases}
1 \text{ when } 0 \leq x<a,\\
0 \text{ when } a<x \leq x_{max}.
\end{cases}
$$
For the second ODE I obtained
$$
- \frac{\mathrm{d}y_2}{\mathrm{d}x} = \begin{cases}
1 \text{ when } 0 \leq x<a,\\
0 \text{ when } a<x \leq x_{max}.
\end{cases} \iff \\
y_2 = \begin{cases}
x+c \text{ when } 0 \leq x<a,\\
0 \text{ when } a<x \leq x_{max}.
\end{cases}
$$
I am unsure how to determine that constant since the only knowledge that I have is at
$x_{max}$, knowledge that I've already used.

For the third ODE I obtained
$$
y_3 = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{2} + c_1 x + c_2 \text{ when } 0 \leq x<a,\\
0 \text{ when } a<x \leq x_{max}.
\end{cases}
$$
where again I do not know how to determine the constants.

So, the question is how to correctly solve these three ODEs with their adjacent boundary conditions for the $y_i(x)$ functions.

Comment: You can always shift the Laplace transform to insert input data where you need it: $\int_b^\infty e^{-s(t-b)} f(t) dt = \int_0^\infty e^{-st} f(t+b) dt$.

Comment: This is probably how I would hand-solve this problem, either that or just change variables to be more convenient (change the direction of time and shift things so the domain is $[0,x_{max}]$ and the initial data is at $0$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to obtain the condition for the second ODE, we use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
$$
y_2(a+\epsilon)-y_2(a-\epsilon)=\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}y_2'(x)\,dx
=-\epsilon,
$$
which implies continuity ​of $y_2$ at $x=a$:$^{(a)}$
$$
y_2(a^-)=y_2(a^+) \Rightarrow -a+c=0 \Rightarrow c=a.
$$
Applying the same argument to the third ODE, we conclude that $y_3'$ and $y_3$ must also be continuous at $x=a$, so that
$$
y_3'(a^-)=y_3'(a^+) \Rightarrow a+c_1=0 \Rightarrow c_1=-a; \\
y_3(a^-)=y_3(a^+) \Rightarrow \frac{a^2}{2}-a^2+c_2=0 \Rightarrow 
c_2=\frac{a^2}{2}.
$$

---

$^{(a)}$Note that $y_2(x)=-x+c$ if $0\leq x<a$, as $-y_2(x)=1$ in this region.

---

ADDENDUM: Solution by Laplace transform

Let me show how the problem may also be solved using the Laplace transform. The key is to consider $y(0)$, $y'(0)$, etc. as coefficients to be determined a posteriori. I will show how this procedure works by solving the second ODE,
$$
y''(x)=\delta(x-a). \tag{A.1}
$$
Applying the Laplace transform to both sides of (A.$1$) yields
$$
-y'(0)-sy(0)+s^2\mathcal{L}[y]=e^{-as}. \tag{A.2}
$$
Solving for $\mathcal{L}[y]$ and taking the inverse transform we obtain
\begin{align*}
y(x)&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{y'(0)}{s^2}+\frac{y(0)}{s}
+\frac{e^{-as}}{s^2}\right] \\
&=[y'(0)x+y(0)]H(x)+(x-a)H(x-a), \tag{A.3}
\end{align*}
where $H$ is the Heaviside step function. (Note that $y(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$, as argued in the first part of the answer.)

Now, let us apply the conditions $y(x_{max})=0, y'(x_{max})=0$ to (A.$3$). The latter implies
$$
y'(0)+1=0 \Rightarrow y'(0)=-1; \tag{A.4}
$$
the former then implies
$$
[y'(0)+1]x_{max}+[y(0)-a]=0 \Rightarrow y(0)=a. \tag{A.5}
$$
Combining the last three equations we finally obtain
$$
y(x)=(-x+a)[H(x)-H(x-a)]=
\begin{cases}-x+a,&\mathrm{if}\, 0\leq x<a, \\
0,&\mathrm{if}\, a\leq x\leq x_{max},
\end{cases} \tag{A.6}
$$
which agrees with the result obtained in the first part of the answer.